# Event handling and networking

Tags: linux, usb, events

The basic use case I have in mind here is network transparent keyboard/mouse/pen/midi events. (Timing latency is not a serious issue yet.) There are two questions.

1. If I plug in a USB keyboard our mouse, how do I capture the events from it, and for them not to go to any other process?

I then want to be able to send events (possibly after processing) to another machine on the network. (Security and authentication is not an issue yet since for now I just want this to work on my Lan between Linux computers).

2. How can a program generate (virtual) keyboard and mouse events as if a user physically used a (probably Usb) keyboard/mouse on that machine? (Needing root privileges is not a problem here.)

If you're wondering why, I have a number of Linux laptops, and many usb keyboards and mice and suchlike. I'd like to develop a means to just say 'take this Usb keyboard and send the events to machine Xyz'.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/).

> Synergy combines your desktop devices together in to one cohesive experience. It's software for sharing your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers on your desk. It works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: I would still like to know how it is done at a low level. I'd like the device capture and network transmission mechanisms from synergy, but the rest isn't necessarily what I'm after. For example if I want usb keyboard A (plugged into machine 1) to send keys to machine 2, inserting various macro processing along the way (so pressing x on keyboard A will cause a script to run, for example), synergy doesn't do that so far as I can tell.